# Jquery load with variables

Tags: jquery, variables, load

can someone tell me where i'm wrong here http://jsfiddle.net/djevrek/Y9rEj/

What i want here is to scan all #divHolder divs in page, finds if that div have div with class that stats with sa_ and then, add in that div, lets say (sa_icon) content with load from page html.html from div with same class (sa_icon).

So, to be more precise, i want to make icon for help, and when user clicks on that icon to populate content in popups div with content from external html page.

So, in my demo, solution 1 works, but now like i want it, it populates all divs it can find, and in solution 2 (click2) doesn't work at all when i'm using jquery load with variables.

In those demos, i'm using load for current page and he finds div #documentation-info that's part of jsfiddle site. What i want is to that part of code be same like class in popup icon div.

Answer (score 0):

`#divHolder` should be unique because IDs should be unique. Try using a class instead, you should achieve more expecting results ;-)

EDIT: in the second method, you're passing a second argument to load(), which is not correct. It should be:

```
    var url2 = "/";
    var sta = "#documentation-info";
    $(this).load(url2+' '+sta);
```

Comment: @Capsuje i dont get you. Please explain me more. I'm having like 500 divs in my page, and about 50 od them have that "divHolder" divs, so i need to scan only those divs that have #divHolder and so what i need to do. So, as far as i understand your comment, you're telling me to specify class instead of divs, and that is not possible in my example.

Comment: You can only have one #divHolder, you should change <div id="divHolder"> to <div class="divHolder"> and then use div.divHolder instead of #divHolder in your jQuery selectors.

Comment: Script woks absolutely same with that ... I dont' have problem with selectors there, AFAIK, but with variables.

Comment: See my edit, your load() call is wrong. It doesn't change the fact an ID should be unique ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks, that was stupid about me :) Now, how can i pass variable "sta" to be same like selected div. So, lets say, he founds 50 divs with "div[class*='sa_']" filter, and i want it later to call load for url /test.html but with div class same like founded in earlier call.
Also, when i click on one button, he do that for every div, and i want it to do only for current div, so i don't need to load 49 divs just to see for one. 
I updated demo, and thanks for answer.

Comment: you `sta` variable must be a string so you have to pass it something like the ID of the mapped div or any other jQuery selector (but not a jQuery object, like you tried). As I said, the best way is to have a different ID for each div, use "div div[class*='sa_']" instead of "#divHolder div[class*='sa_']" and then find the right ID by using $(this).attr('id')

Comment: I'm still not understanding, sorry. My real example is like this
`<div class="helpicon"><div class="helpdesc sa_logo" title="Custom Logo"></div></div>` and i want when someone click on .helpicon to insert content from html.html and from div with same name as last class, sa_logo. So, i have about 50 divs like helpicon and all of them have different sa_* classes. Also, in help.html i have also 50 classes with same name which content need to be inserted on first page with click. I hope you understand me now. What i'm making is some kind of popup help with populating from help.html file on click